# jQuery inArray doesn't work when the first element matches

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to check an array that I create as to whether or not a value is in the array (anywhere) at all or not. If the value is anywhere in the array it needs to do one thing, else another.

```
var Arr = [false, false, false, false, false];
// It works with the following:
// Arr = [true, false, false, false, false]

if(!$.inArray(false, Arr))
{
        //False is not in the array at all - so continue with code  
}
else
{
       //False was found in the array
}
```

So this above code is working as if the if statement is true, however it clearly isn't.

If I change the array to: `true, false, false, false, false` the if statement is then false though, as it should be.

Basically what I need this code to do is to only be true if every value in the array is `true`.

Comment: It's a poorly named method. They should have called it `indexOf()` like the standard method `Arr.indexOf(false) === -1`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`$.inArray` returns the index of the item or `-1` if no items were found:

```
if ($.inArray(false, Arr) > -1) {
  // found
} else {
  // not found
}
```

Always useful to check the docs first: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Answer (score 5):

> [`jQuery.inArray( value, array [, fromIndex ] )`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) Returns: Number
>
> Description: Search for a specified value within an array and return
>   its index (or -1 if not found).

inArray returns an integer!

So when it is at index at 0 it would be a falsely value!

You need to check > -1